# How can I extract values from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries called "empty_list"

```
[{u'course': 123,
  u'lat': 123,
  u'lon': 123,
  u'navigationalStatus': 0.0,
  u'sog': 0.0,
  u'ts': 123,
  u'Id': u'abcd'},
 {u'course': 123,
  u'lat': 123,
  u'lon': 123,
  u'navigationalStatus': 0.0,
  u'sog': 123,
  u'ts': 123,
  u'Id': u'abcde'}]
```

Bsically I want to get a list, `new_list`

```
[(u'abcd', lat, lon),
 (u'abcde', lat, lon)]
```

When I do this:

```
new_list = []
for item in empty_list:
    new_list.append(( item['Id'],item['lat'], item['lon']))
```

I get `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

But it seems to work anyway. The problem is that `new_list` has a length of only 24 (when `empty_list` had a length of 288).

Do you have any idea how I can debug that?

Comment: Are you sure? Your exact code doesn't raise any error for me, and works perfectly fine. On a side note, don't use the name `empty_list` if the list isn't empty..

Comment: It could be because some entries in your `emptyList` are not dicts. The error implies that some entries could be lists themselves

Comment: How can I check if all the entries are dict?

Comment: You can debug that by printing the type of item inside the for loop. Printing `type(item) == dict` should work

Comment: Try `from collections import Counter; Counter(map(type, empty_list))` to print out counts for each type in your initial `empty_list`.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate your list into two dictionaries

```
e 
[{'Id': 'abcd',
  'course': 123,
  'lat': 123,
  'lon': 123,
  'navigationalStatus': 0.0,
  'sog': 0.0,
  'ts': 123},
 {'Id': 'abcde',
  'course': 123,
  'lat': 123,
  'lon': 123,
  'navigationalStatus': 0.0,
  'sog': 123,
  'ts': 123}]
```

Then

```
chunks = [e[x:x+1] for x in range(0, 2)]
c0 = chunks[0][0]
c1 = chunks[1][0]
```

Now you have c0

```
{'Id': 'abcd',
 'course': 123,
 'lat': 123,
 'lon': 123,
 'navigationalStatus': 0.0,
 'sog': 0.0,
 'ts': 123}
```

You can unpack keys and values and then choose whichever you want

```
keys, values = dict.keys(c0), dict.values(c0)
keys
dict_keys(['course', 'lat', 'lon', 'navigationalStatus', 'sog', 'ts', 'Id'])
values
dict_values([123, 123, 123, 0.0, 0.0, 123, 'abcd'])
```